# What is the Pythonic way to write a single line text in multiple lines

Tags: python

I need to print a long const sentence in a python script and we follow the "not more than 80 chars a line" rule.

I know the following would work but is there a better way to write this?

```
print ("This is a reaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaally long "
       "sentencexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").format("")
```

or,

```
print ("This is a reaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaally long " +
        "sentencexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
```

Or, if one of them is preferable than the other one.

Edit:To make it more clear, the expected output is,

`This is a reaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaally long sentencexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Comment: While your multiline strings have parenthesis - you can avoid backslashes, concatenation, formatting etc

Comment: @user2263572 No, it's not. That's about multiline strings, this question is about writing a single line string in multiple line.

Comment: The answer below is from the link I posted. This is a dupe.

Comment: @user2263572 I see. Yes, you're right.

Comment: Your first example does not violate any PEP rules; the answer you've accepted *does*. You first example is perfectly fine, but note that `.format("")` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a better way:

```
print(
"This is a reaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaally long "
"sentence"
)
```

Actually, you need nothing to concatenate strings.

Comment: Ah, I mistakenly put a comma and that's why it was complaining. Thanks for the answer.